# Month-wise pivot in SQL Server (month will change dynamically)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table on my sale data to month-wise data which are shown below.

I have added table code and data list

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductList]
(
    [Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SaleDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [Unit] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is the data:

```
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Beauty Cosmetics', N'Face Pack', CAST(N'2021-02-06T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 200, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Beauty Cosmetics', N'Facial Kit', CAST(N'2021-02-07T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 43, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Beauty Cosmetics', N'Face Pack', CAST(N'2020-03-04T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 200, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Beauty Cosmetics', N'Facial Kit', CAST(N'2020-03-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 43, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Body Care Products', N'Body Lotion', CAST(N'2020-01-02T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 100, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Body Care Products', N'Hair Removal Cream', CAST(N'2020-01-03T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 323, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Body Care Products', N'Sunscreen Lotion', CAST(N'2020-01-04T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 321, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Body Care Products', N'Petroleum Jelly', CAST(N'2020-09-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 54, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Body Care Products', N'Hair Removal Cream', CAST(N'2021-02-08T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 32, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Body Care Products', N'Sunscreen Lotion', CAST(N'2021-02-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 211, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Face Cream', N'Fairness Cream', CAST(N'2021-02-03T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Face Cream', N'Men Fairness Cream', CAST(N'2021-02-04T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 32, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Face Cream', N'Facial Cream', CAST(N'2021-02-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Face Cream', N'Fairness Cream', CAST(N'2021-02-13T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 12, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Face Cream', N'Men Fairness Cream', CAST(N'2021-02-14T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 23, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Lip Cosmetics', N'Lipstick', CAST(N'2020-03-04T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 12, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Lip Cosmetics', N'Matte Lipstick', CAST(N'2021-02-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 212, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Lip Cosmetics', N'Lip Guard', CAST(N'2021-02-02T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 212, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Lip Cosmetics', N'Lip Gloss', CAST(N'2021-02-10T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 12, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Lip Cosmetics', N'Matte Lipstick', CAST(N'2021-02-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 12, N'PC')
INSERT [dbo].[ProductList] ([Product], [ProductName], [SaleDate], [Price], [Unit]) VALUES (N'Lip Cosmetics', N'Lip Guard', CAST(N'2021-02-12T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 121, N'PC')
```

I want to like this

```
ProductCatagory ProductName     Sale2020    Feruary March   April   May
Beauty Cosmetics    Face Pack   200      0       0       0       0
Beauty Cosmetics    Face Pack   200      0       0       0       0
Beauty Cosmetics    Face Pack   0        200     0       0       0
Beauty Cosmetics    Facial Kit  0        43      0       0       0
Beauty Cosmetics    Facial Kit  43       0       0       0       0
```

I want this to dynamically change as the months move on with the current month and a total.

Comment: I would recommend that you don't utilize [2020] as a column title. Not only is this typically frowned upon in most naming conventions (only numeric), it also limits the use of this query to only ever return values for the year 2020. Additionally, there is no way to dynamically change the number of columns within your result set or the actual column names in the result set without the usage of dynamic SQL, which I would also highly recommend against here (simple aggregate query). You should see if there is a way for you to utilize a more 'best practice' result set and avoid using dynamic sql.

Comment: yes it will sale2020

Comment: As @trenton-ftw mentioned, even if you use `sale2020` as column name, what if the year changes? It is always better to handle such things in the frontend and in SQL, keep column name as `CurrentYear`. Also, for dynamic months, I would recommend you to show all 12 months and put 0 against future month figures. You can then filter future months out in the frontend.